# Blank Image - Image intervention Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I save a image using the Image Intervention class my file saves but shows as blank. I send it a base64 string.

**Currently My Code.**

```
    $file = Input::file($_POST['data']);
    $img = Image::make($file);

    $fileName = "profiles/".md5(time()).'.png';

    $path = public_path($fileName);

    if($img->save($path)){

        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
        $user->location->start_image = $fileName;
        $user->push();
    }
```

**print_r($_POST['data'])** ->  http://pastebin.com/BGbUeZhr

Thanks

- I have tried  $file = Input::file(base64_decode($_POST['data'])); This does not work

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I got this right... but if you're loading the image as a string, shouldn't you be using ``Input::get('data')`` rather than ``Input::file($_POST['data'])``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but using `Input::file` when you have the image as base64 looks just wrong to me. `Input::file` is for retrieving a file that has been upload with an html form.

Assuming `$_POST['data']` is a base64 encoded image, try this:

```
$img = Image::make($_POST['data']);
```

Or even better:

```
$img = Image::make(Input::get('data'));
```