# Laravel 5.8 display description and change picture profile

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I try to create/modify a profile, but when I want to add an image in profile, it doesn't work and doesn't load into the database.

**ProfileController**

```php
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function show(User $user)
    {
        return view('profile.show', compact('user'));
    }

    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        $this->authorize('update', $user->profile);
        return view('profile.edit', compact('user'));
    }

    public function update(User $user)
    {
        $this->authorize('update', $user->profile);
        $data = request()->validate([
            'description' => 'required',
            'image' => 'sometimes|image|max:3000'
        ]);

        if (request('image')) {
            $imagePath = request('image')->store('avatars', 'public');

            $image = Image::make(public_path("/storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(800, 800);
            $image->save();

            auth()->user()->profile->update(array_merge($data,
                ['image' => $imagePath]
            ));
        } else {
            auth()->user()->profile->update($data);
        }

        auth()->user()->profile->update($data);

        return redirect()->route('profile.show', ['user' => $user]);
    }
}
```

**User**

```php
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'nom', 'prenom', 'adresse', 'ville',
        'codepostale', 'datedenaissance', 'email', 'password',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::created(function ($user) {
            $user->profile()->create([
                'description' => $user->username
            ]);
        });
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'username';
    }

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }
}
```

**show.blade.php**

```php
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="{{ $user->profile->getImage() }}" class="rounded-circle w-100" alt="" style="max-width: 240px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-baseline">
                    <div class="h4 mr-3 pt-2">{{ $user->username }}</div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">S'abonner</button>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <div class="mr-3">{{ $user->posts->count() }} article(s) en vente
                    </div>
                    @can('update', $user->profile)
                        <a href=" {{ route('profile.edit', ['username' => $user->username]) }}">Modifier Profile</a>
                    @endcan
                    <div class="mt-3">
                        <div class="font-weight-bold">
                            {{ $user->profile->title }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-5">
                @foreach ($user->posts as $post)
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <a href="{{ route('posts.show', ['post' => $post->id]) }}">
                            <img src="{{ asset('storage') . '/' . $post->image }}" alt="" class="w-100">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

edit.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Modifier profile</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('profile.update', ['user' => $user]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        @method('PATCH')

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="description">Description</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <textarea id="description" type="text" class="form-control @error('description') is-invalid @enderror" name="description" autocomplete="description" autofocus>{{ old('description') ?? $user->profile->description }}</textarea>

                                @error('description')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">    
                            <div class="custom-file">

                                <input type="file" name="image" class="custom-file-input @error('image') is-invalid @enderror" id="validatedCustomFile" >
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="validatedCustomFile">Choisir une image</label>
                                @error('image')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Modifier profile
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**Profile.php**

```php
class Profile extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['description']; 

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function getImage()
    {
        $imagePath = $this->image ?? 'avatars/default.png';

        return "/storage/" . $imagePath;
    }
}
```

**create_profiles_tables.php**

```php
class CreateProfilesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('profiles');
    }
}
```

I don't know what problem for uploads pictures in the database and change profile picture, can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, you are attempting to update the **image** field of the user's related **Profile** model.

```php
auth()->user()->profile->update(array_merge($data,
    ['image' => $imagePath]
));
```

However, in your **Profile** model, **image** is not an allowed field for mass assignment.

```php
protected $fillable = ['description'];
```

You should change this to:

```php
protected $fillable = ['description','image'];
```

Hope this helps and good luck!

**EDIT**

> Follow up to blank image problem.

Based on that other solution I linked, I'm able to determine from the documentation that there are multiple ways to use the Intervention Image package.

Try changing this:

```php
$image = Image::make(public_path("/storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(800, 800);
$image->save();
```

To this:

```php
$image = Image::make(Input::file('image'))->fit(800, 800);
$image->save(public_path("/storage/{$imagePath}"));
```

Perhaps you will have better luck with this method, just as the user did in the other thread.

**Intervention Image** (documentation)

`make()` http://image.intervention.io/api/make

`save()` http://image.intervention.io/api/save

**EDIT**

> Further follow-up

Have you properly linked your public storage?  If not, this could be a contributing factor.

```php
php artisan storage:link
```

It's going to be very difficult for me to debug your app remotely.  But I would start by creating some simple controller methods for testing.

First, create a controller method to return a known good image. This would be one that you have placed directly on the server in a specific location.  Then reference that path accordingly, and call the method from a route.

```php
public function untouchedImage()
{
    $path = public_path('images/known-good-image.png');
    return response()->file(public_path($path);
}
```

Then, if the image above displays properly, create another controller method. Reference the exact same file location but attempt to output a resized image.

```php
public function resizedImage()
{
    $path = public_path('images/known-good-image.png');
    $image = Image::make(path)->resize(40,40);

    return $image->response('png');
}
```

If this works, then the problem is likely with your image paths.  You will need to dump the paths line by line in your app while you are saving the image to see what is going wrong.

If it doesn't work, then you likely have a misconfiguration somewhere with Laravel or PHP.  Do you have the proper PHP image libraries loaded on your server?  It uses GD by default or Imagick through the config.

Comment: ok thanks my friend))) it works in half, i need to change protected $fillable = ['description','image'];  but picture its white

Comment: The image is white?  Or the image isn't being loaded?  Can you check your console to see if the image URL is invalid?

Comment: in my console i have this [Mon Jul 15 15:16:34 2019] 127.0.0.1:33804 [200]: /storage/uploads/6FcQZPW4bKmnIWKmmfy0FiZ3tsCfPXj0Un63sM7O.jpeg

Comment: Appears to be a 200 response, so a file exists.  Are you using `Intervention` for the image cropping?  If so, here is a link where others have had the same issue.  https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/501  Some mention it could be due to an extra space in a config file somewhere, but I am not familiar with the package.  And another, https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/493.

Comment: Oh, check this one out.  It looks promising.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402776/blank-image-image-intervention-laravel

Comment: i look and i don't understand what i need to doing?

Comment: I have updated my answer with something for you to try.

Comment: I have updated my response with some further information on how you might approach debugging the issue.  I also installed the Intervention Image dependency on my own Laravel 5.8 server and was able to use to use the above methods without any issues, so it doesn't appear to be a problem with the package.